# Mudar Login [Gem Devise Ruby On Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, login, devise

A gem devise cria um sistema de login com e-mail e senha. Como faço para alterar a forma de login de e-mail para um código, ou seja, em vez de o usuário fazer login pelo e-mail ele entrar com um número ou nome?

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma migration para adicionar o nome de usuário:

```
$ rails generate migration add_username_to_users username:string
```

Rode a migration:

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

Altere o arquivo /config/initializers/devise.rb trocando :email por :username

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]
```

Por fim, mude sua view:

```
<li><%= f.label :username %> <%= f.text_field :username %></li>
```

Referência: [railscasts](http://railscasts)

Answer (score 0):

Ainda não precisei fazer isso, mas tem essa wiki do devise que demonstra bem como usar um `username` (ou código) para fazer o login.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address